# says there are errors mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

this is so that I come from Denmark and use google translate because I'm bad at English so hope that it can be in level with, however, this is how my MySQLI code to go right down to the last words, and says there are errors . I've tried to write it right password and email in, but it can not be bothered to work at all in some way it keeps making mistakes, how can it be?

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include("include/database/db.php"); 

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, djnavn, hemmelig, rank FROM `brugere` WHERE `email` = ? AND `password` = ?"))
            {
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $djnavn, $hemmelig, $rank);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $count_res = $stmt->num_rows;
            $stmt->close();

            if($count_res > 0) {
                $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true;
                $_SESSION["user_id"] = $id;
                $_SESSION["djnavn"] = $djnavn;
                $_SESSION["hemmelig"] = $hemmelig;
                $_SESSION["rank"] = $rank;
                if($rank == 0)
                {
                    echo "Your can not log in!";
                }
                if($rank == 1)
                {
                    echo "Ok, members you can log in now!";
                }
                if($rank == 2)
                {
                    echo "Ok, Admin you can log in now!";
                }
            }
            else {
                echo 'fail her: ' . $mysqli->error; 
            }
        }
?>
```

**Can you help me on it!!**

Comment: And does your query work directly against the database? Say, in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: so what is the error? :)

Comment: I see a few errors myself `notice: undefined email and also password` and your binding before there set

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's notification and it occurs because you don't define $email and $password before you use them.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
```

cut and paste them befor you bind params:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
```

Comment: what do you think such a hero?

Comment: nvm. - what do you mean?,, what to do completely?

Comment: it does not at all by any means, hmm